# Drush migration no longer working in 8.5

Tags: 8, drush, migrations

I've been migrating a site from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. The site was 8.4 when I ran the migrations. I've since updated the site to Drupal 8.5. Now, when I type `drush migration-status` or any migration-related command, I get the following error:

```
[error]  The file_entity plugin must define the source_module property.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok answering this myself. I keep forgetting that Drupal often introduces breaking changes and treats comments as code. It looks like [the annotation changed in 8.5](https://www.drupal.org/node/2914530)

What was in 8.4:

```
/**
 * Drupal 7 file_entity source from database.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "file_entity",
 *   source_provider = "file"
 * )
 */
```

in 8.5 should now be:

```
/**
 * Drupal 7 file_entity source from database.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "file_entity",
 *   source_module = "file",
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Would a slight change in annotation really effect the functionality of Drush? Besides the references page and the given examples talk about 7, but you say you have 8.

Comment: @AltaGrade Not drush as a whole, but running any migration-related drush command threw an error. I fixed one annotation, and then drush migrations worked again.

Comment: Really strange as annotations are not part of executed code, they are just notes. So I do believe something else is going on here.

Comment: @AltaGrade If you find another way to resolve the issue, please let me know. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins